# How to add spinner hint as last item to JSON response

Tags: android, json

I am trying to add SELECT option to spinner which i populate from rest service.
I have added the decrease the count of item by one to the adapter class.
How to add spinner hint as last item to JSON response.

```
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                   ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();

   for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
     try {
            JSONObject c = response.getJSONObject(i);
            String  employeeIdArray = c.getString("employeeId");

            spinnerArray.add("SELECT ONE");

            spinnerArray.add(employeeIdArray);
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
              }
        }

final SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(MainActivity.this, spinnerArray);

spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
spinner.setSelection(adapter.getCount());
```

In adapter

```
   public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> employeeIds) {
        super(context, R.layout.spinner_id, employeeIds);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // don't display last item. It is used as hint.
        int count = super.getCount();
        return count > 0 ? count - 1 : count;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView employeeId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String employeeIds = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_id, parent, false);

            viewHolder.employeeId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.value_employee_employeeId);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.employeeId.setText(employeeIds);

        return convertView;

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add that hint in main spinnerArray, after creating object of this adapter

```
final SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(MainActivity.this, spinnerArray);
```

add hint in adapter array SpinnerAdapter() constructor like this

```
public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> employeeIds) {
    super(context, R.layout.spinner_id, employeeIds);
    employeeIds.add("SELECT ONE")
}
```

and in your get count simply do this

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // don't display last item. It is used as hint.
    int count = super.getCount();
    return count > 0 ? count - 1 : count;
}
```

and in get view method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String employeeIds = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_id, parent, false);

        viewHolder.employeeId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.value_employee_employeeId);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (position == getCount()) {
        viewHolder.employeeId.setText("");
        viewHolder.employeeId.setHint(employeeIds); //"Hint to be displayed"
    } else {
        viewHolder.employeeId.setText(employeeIds);
    }
    return convertView;
```

}

and then this two lines will wok perfectly

```
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
spinner.setSelection(adapter.getCount());
```

Comment: Please check my adapter class. How to add spinnerArray in adapter .

Comment: in SpinnerAdapter()
{ employeeIDs.add("Select One")}
 just after super()

Comment: Yeah did the changes. I have got 14 records, so it displays the last id 14 instead of select one. Select one is inside the drop down box.

Comment: Select one is must added at last in the list

Comment: If i interchange the last 2 lines in activity class select one is on top, but can't see 14 inside the drop down box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122380/discussion-between-bhoomit-bb-and-user3785322).

Answer (score 1):

`spinnerArray.add("SELECT ONE");` add After for loop